# Are there any references to 'Excalibur' comics in Thor: The Dark World?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

I recently attended a lecture about transmedia franchising, in which the lecturer remarked:

> Marvel are a company who never pass up a self-referential opportunity,
>   no matter how obscure.

Whilst I'm aware that this was largely intended to be hyberbolic, the context of the discussion was engaged with explaining how different Marvel properties will signal fans by placing easter eggs in the work, even if it references a property that the work doesn't directly own/benefit from.

Given that [Thor: The Dark World](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1981115/) has long sequences set in England, I wondered if there was any reference to Excalibur featured within it?

I also posted [this question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/17084/what-is-the-significance-of-southend-on-sea) which seemed to demonstrate some obscure (and as yet unidentified) reference, could the two be linked?

Comment: Aren't *Excalibur comics* is a part of x-men? So can Marvel break Fox's distribution right? I'm not a comic geek so I may not be right.

Comment: Fox own the rights to certain members of the X-Men Franchise, and the term 'Mutants' (and it's derivatives). Whilst *Excalibur* prominently features members of the X-Men, it is set in the wider Marvel Universe (616): also, any franchise can *reference* characters implicitly, as part of a wider world-building strategy... But it would be interesting if anyone has proof that the MCU is unable to reference *Excalibur* due to Fox's ownership...?

Comment: A quick side note - There are actually a bunch of Marvel UK characters and teams, not just Excalibur, that could have been alluded to in Thor II: Union Jack, Captain Britain, Micromax, Dark Angel, Death's Head, MI-13, Black Air, Knights of Pendragon... just to name a few.

Comment: you're correct of course, but I'd hoped I was encapsulating/acknowledging the wider range of British Marvel Hero's within the context of the question. Feel free to edit it if you think it needs to be more explicit

Answer (score 1):

Unless you count a lighthouse - which could be a nod or it could be a coincidence - I'm not aware of any Excalibur easter eggs. The Thor mythos didn't really overlap much with the Excalibur team, so most of the easter eggs in Thor 2 are limited to those references that did. References to material outside of the Thor mythos included X-Force, Dr. Strange, The Infinity War, and Guardians of the Galaxy.

Comment: What X-Force easter egg was there?

Comment: Selvig's chalkboard at the asylum had "Kyle + Yost = X", which is a reference to X-Force writers Craig Kyle and Chris Yost. Also, the mercenaries in the Asgardian prison were called "The Marauders", which is a team largely featured in X-Force arcs.